# How to automate foreach in php and check if created arrays are empty?

Tags: php, arrays

I have lots of foreaches in my app and I would like to automate the process and also check if the created arrays are empty. So, basically this is my old code:

```
foreach ($array as $a) {
    $arr1[] = $a->metric
    $arr2[] = $a->metric2
}
```

And then:

```
if (!empty($arr1)) {
    // do stuff with $arr1
}
```

I thought a class with __construct and __get might help. So, this is my approach:

```
class CheckMetric  {

function __contruct($valueArray, $metricArray) {
    foreach ($valueArray as $value) {
        foreach ($metricArray as $metric) {
            $metrics[] = $value->$metric;    
        }
        $this->$metric = $metrics;
    }
}

function __get($metric) {
    if (empty($this->$metric)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public function returnMetric($metric) {
    return $this->$metric;
}

}
```

Now I thought I'd be able to do this:

```
$metricArray = ['metric1', 'metric2', 'metric3'];
$valueArray = Model::find(); // data from my model

$checkMetric = new CheckMetric($valueArray, $metricArray);

if ($checkMetric->metric1) {
    // do stuff with $checkMetric->metric1
}
```

But I'm not! What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made two things wrong in your CheckMetric class, i guess.

First you iterate over the `$valueArray` but you need a specific metric name from `$metricArray` as a key. Switch the loops. First over `$metricArray` and in the inner loop over `$valueArray`.

Within the class you set non existent property. Yes, that works, but if you set a property with e.g. "metric2", the magic getter `__get` will not be executed anymore. So, use a protected/private array as a metric storage instead.

```
<?php

class CheckMetric {

    /** @var array */
    protected $metrics = [];

    /**
     * @param string[] $valueArray
     * @param string[] $metricArray
     */
    function __construct($valueArray, $metricArray)
    {
        foreach ($metricArray as $metric) {
            $metrics = [];

            foreach ($valueArray as $value) {
                $metrics[] = $value->$metric;
            }

            $this->metrics[$metric] = $metrics;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $metric
     * @return bool
     */
    function __get($metric)
    {
        return isset($this->metrics[$metric]);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $metric
     * @return array
     */
    public function returnMetric($metric)
    {
        return isset($this->metrics[$metric])
            ? $this->metrics[$metric] 
            : [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

doing $this->$metric = ... means your making a local variable, alike $metric.
but if you remove the extra $ in $this->**$**metric then yes, a property of the class.
and you should modify the property's visibility to public by doing :

```
public $metric;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

in the class but not inside a function.
so :
    class CheckMetric  {

```
    public $metric;

    public function __contruct($valueArray, $metricArray) {
        foreach ($valueArray as $value) {
            foreach ($metricArray as $metric) {
                $metrics[] = $value->$metric;    
            }
            $this->metric = $metrics;
       }
   }

    public function __get($metric) {
        if (empty($this->$metric)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function returnMetric($metric) {
        return $this->$metric;
    }
}
```

You could also use [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php).